# Average of a groupby or a groupby of an average on a dataframe with duplicated indexes

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe in this format:

```
               value    identifier
2007-01-01  0.087085      55
2007-01-01  0.703249      56
2007-02-01  0.967872      55
2007-02-01  0.954142      56
2008-01-01  0.804404      55
2008-01-01  0.475372      56
2008-02-01  0.025823      55
2008-02-01  0.414736      56
```

I need to do a boxplot by month. There are two ways of how I'm doing it: first to groupby by the index, copy to a new dataframe, and do a groupby by month:

```
by_index = dd.groupby(dd.index).mean()
temp = pd.DataFrame()
temp['value']  =by_index['value']
by_month = temp.groupby(lambda x: x.month)
by_month.boxplot(subplots=False)
```

Or first groupby month, take the mean and plot directly:

```
by_month = dd.groupby(lambda x: x.month)
by_month_avg = by_month.mean()
by_month_avg['value'].plot()
```

The problem is that the means between the two methods differ. What is the correct approach? Should the two results be equal?

Comment: Not sure what the question is.  Means aren't the same because in the former approach jan2007 and jan2008 are distinct but in the latter are the same (because jan is jan regardless of year).  Neither is more correct, just depends which one you want.

Comment: They're again grouped by month in the first case, so in the end they are the same - exactly my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the confusion is because you are using a different syntax in the two cases and it's less obvious what the difference is.  You're using lambda to operate on the index in the one case:

```
dd.groupby(lambda x: x.month).mean()
```

Alternatively, you could do it like this (similar to what you did in the other case):

```
dd.groupby( dd.index.month ).mean()
```

It should then be clear why the above gives a different answer than:

```
dd.groupby( dd.index ).mean()
```

In the one case, results are the means by date, in the other they are by month.  Maybe this print dump will also help:

```
dd.index.date

array([datetime.date(2007, 1, 1), datetime.date(2007, 1, 1),
       datetime.date(2007, 2, 1), datetime.date(2007, 2, 1),
       datetime.date(2008, 1, 1), datetime.date(2008, 1, 1),
       datetime.date(2008, 2, 1), datetime.date(2008, 2, 1)], dtype=object)

dd.index.month
array([1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2])
```

I just added the 'date' attribute to make it print cleaner, but the idea is unchanged.  The former groupby has 4 groups, the latter has 2.

Based on a followup question, I am wondering if what you really want is to group by month and year?

```
dd.groupby([dd.index.year,dd.index.month]).mean()

           value  identifier
2007 1  0.395167        55.5
     2  0.961007        55.5
2008 1  0.639888        55.5
     2  0.220279        55.5
```

Comment: The dd.index.month helps a lot to make the code clearer, but I would imagine that the groupby by dd.index would make a groupby for each day. The results should be the same if each month only had one day, right?

Comment: Almost. It's a groupby **date**, not **day**, so the answer also depends on year.  Maybe you want:  ```dd.groupby([dd.index.year,dd.index.month]).mean()```

Comment: Look that the identifier now is 55.5, without any meaning.